# Server side of extending an object in Outlook for multiple clients 

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

If I want to make my own outlook object that extends the already existing class do I need to do anything on the server side? I want to make an add in where you can send and receive a type of task that is an extension of outlooks standard tasks. People using this add in will most likely be using exchange server. Is there anything that needs to be done on the server side in order to use this new task object, or is it possible to do it all on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage your custom **Task** by doing everything on the client-side. All that is required is creating a new [`MessageClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867813.aspx) that extends from the [existing message class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb176446%28v=office.12%29.aspx) of `IPM.Task`

```cs
 mailItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Task.MyCompany.TaskType";
 mailItem.Save(); // persist change
```

See MSDN for `MessageClass` [naming guidelines and applying custom Form Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157886.aspx).

In terms of publishing the custom form to a *Form Library*, use a VSTO Setup Project and it will install to the users' **Personal Forms Library**. See [this reference regarding publishing outlook forms](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=34). Traditional Outlook Forms (*designed using Outlook*) can be published to the **Organizational Forms Library** (*enterprise-wide*) - but VSTO forms are only published to **Personal Forms Library**.

Comment: In terms of publishing the forms though, do I need to do anything on the server side? I know there's the organizational forms library on exchange server that you can published too (it can be assumed that those using this add in will also be using exchange server). My only problem with that is that you need to go through whoever the admin would be for the exchange server and then have them give the ok and then they would publish it there. Is there a way to work around this and publish the form for all clients, perhaps in the installation process of the add in?

Comment: I have deployed custom forms via VSTO Setup Project without installing them on Exchange Server. You just need to match `FormRegionMessageClass` in your code with the message class you assign your mailbox item. See above edits regarding deployment.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you!